# spark physicalPlanDescription String is to big

Tags: apache-spark

while running spark job I get OOM exception looking at the stack trace I find that the `physicalPlanDescription` is too big:

it is created here: (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution line: 206)

```
private def completeString(appendStats: Boolean): String = {
...
...
s"""== Parsed Logical Plan ==
   |${stringOrError(logical.treeString(verbose = true))}
   |== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
   |$analyzedPlan
   |== Optimized Logical Plan ==
   |${stringOrError(optimizedPlanString)}
   |== Physical Plan ==
   |${stringOrError(executedPlan.treeString(verbose = true))}
""".stripMargin.trim
}
```

It is created for the UI according to the note in the code.

1) What can I do? already using a driver with a 20G Heap.

2) Why is this string not lazy? why should it be computed always?

I also open Issue: [Apache Spark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23904)

As asked sample code: [link](https://gist.github.com/igreenfield/584c3336f03ba7d63e9026774eaf5e23)

run with `-XX:+UseG1GC`

Just to be clear this code creates a very big plan, my real code is much more complex many tables that join to each other filtering and many `case when` statements.
So please do not stick to the fact that this sample code actually does nothing.

Comment: Can you provide the code that creates dataframe ?

Comment: @nabongs the code involve big CASE WHEN that add as a column to DF

Comment: @igreen Simple reproduction will be very helpful here and on Apache Spark JIRA ;)

Comment: @nabongs I add sample code

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same issue, and solution is to set parameter "spark.sql.ui.retainedExecutions" to lower value, for example `--conf "spark.sql.ui.retainedExecutions=10"`. 
By default it's 1000.
It keeps instances count of org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ui.SQLExecutionUIData low enough.
SQLExecutionUIData have a reference to physicalPlanDescription, which can get very big.
In our case we had to read huge avro messages from Kafka with lot's of fields, and plan description was in the area of 8mg each.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need UI, you can try to set spark.ui.enabled as false.

Comment: It creates this string even if the UI is disabled. these string are created while sending the messages to the bus...

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate the physical plan using `spark.sql.maxPlanStringLength=8000 <number of bytes>` config and control the length of the string that you to display on UI.

Spark introduced this config oin 3.0.0 version.

*Maximum number of characters to output for a plan string. If the plan is longer, further output will be truncated. The default setting always generates a full plan. Set this to a lower value such as 8k if plan strings are taking up too much memory or are causing OutOfMemory errors in the driver or UI processes.*